# Converting RGB image to H&E color space

Tags: colors, rgb, transformation, space, channel

In MATLAB how to convert RGB image to H&E (Hematoxylin and eosin stain)color space for medical imaging?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

H&E is a staining modality (basically a way of coloring different cells in a tissue sample), not a color space. You could have an RGB image *of* a slide that has been stained with hematoxylin and eosin, but you could convert that RGB image to another colorspace (like HSL, CIELab, etc) and it will still be the same image.

For a dumb analogy: you can have a recording of a song and change its key by converting the pitches - so it's in a different key but the song 'information' is preserved akin to switching an image between colorspaces. However, you couldn't switch a rock song to a jazz one by a similar process, you'd have to re-record the song in a jazz style (i.e. switch the staining modality).